# What is the number of native! in Rebol3

Tags: rebol, rebol3

How do I calculate the number native functions in Rebol3?

(**help native!** prints native functions in **lib** but it does not return a block of words.)

UPDATE: I have corrected the question after the error highlighted by @HostileFork.

Comment: what is `lib` ?

Comment: Note that **type? :val = native!** is effectively **type? (:val = native!)**, which is the datatype LOGIC!, which is a "truthy" value.  Hence this just gives you all the declarations in lib.

Comment: @GeekyI `lib` is an alias for the same context as `system/contexts/lib`.  It is where all of the bootstrap definitions are put.  The user context where you typically write (`system/context/user`) is initially a copy of these definitions.  But lib is still available, so even if you overwrite something like `print: func [x] [...]` you can get back at the original definition via `lib/print`.

Comment: @HostileFork thanks, I was thrown off at first because `lib` is only rebol3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A catalog of natives (or at least words of their names) is built at boot time:

```
>> length? system/catalog/natives
== 160
```

There are more definitions in lib than just native routines.  Definitions of typesets and other things.  But almost every native is accessible through it at startup:

```
>> natives: []

>> foreach [word value] lib [if native? :value [append natives word]]

>> length? natives
== 168
```

A few of those differences are accounted for by synonyms (Q for QUIT, --- for COMMENT, etc):

```
>> difference natives system/catalog/natives
== [native action q ! min max --- bind? pwd context]
```

NATIVE and ACTION are special and for whatever reason do not make it into the catalog.

*(Note that in current evolutions of the [Ren-C build of Rebol3](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c), there is only one FUNCTION! datatype.  So there is no NATIVE? or ACTION? etc.  Hence,  `system/catalog/natives` is your only way to find this out.)*

Comment: Thanks @HostileFork, you have been very clear. Sorry for the stupid error in the code (and I think that it is too late to correct the question).Why in Ren-C there is no distinction between FUNCTION!, ACTION! and NATIVE! ?

Comment: @noein [See chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34874083#34874083)

Answer (score 0):

```
num: 0
foreach [w val] lib [if type? :val = native! [++ num]]
```

gives me 700 in a "recent" build of rebol-3

Comment: I know. They should be 150-200. For this reason, the method used by me is wrong.

Comment: `type? :val = native!` is LOGIC!